# Non english characters are not displayed in symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I'm trying to retrieve data from one of my tables in MySQL. I've set up database and symfony 2 to support data exchange in utf8. However, when I want to display for example all categories from "category" table with two columns (id, name), non English characters like Russian are not displayed. In parameters.yml, I've changed locale to ru_RU - no effect. I'm using Doctrine2, Twig in symfony 2.2-DEV. Appreciate any help.

```
<ul>
    {% for category in categories %}
        <li><a href="#">{{ category.id }} : {{ category.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**UPDATE:** I've solved this problem, actually my MySQL Server was set to accept both utf8 and cp1251, and that was a problem. And when i changed everything into utf8 in my.ini, problem has disappeared. I think we can close this question.

Comment: i never used Symfony, but there must be global config file. There must be a character set for the application

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and accept it.